# Pass php object to smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have an issue with passing an object to smarty tag. I have the following code:

```
$contact = new Contacts;
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('contact',$contact);
```

In test.htpl :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{$title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    id: {$contact->id} <br/>
    name: {$contact->name} <br/>
    email: {$contact->email} <br/>
    phone: {$contact->phone} <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

this leads to an warning of invalid character '>'. How can I solve this?

I used this class for testing:

```
class Contacts
{
 public $id = 1;
 public $name = 'Mada';
 public $email = 'mada@yahoo.com';
 public $phone = 123456;
}
```

Comment: can you show us what us in the Contacts Class?

Comment: Googling "smarty template object" lead to http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/advanced.features.php as the first result.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$smarty->assign_by_ref('contact',$contact);
```

This will allow you to access in the way you expect.

Using register_object() is also an option, and allows you to restrict what can be used from the template, but this means a different template format (no initial $).

Answer (score 0):

By doing the following should work

```
$smarty->register_object('contact',$contact);
```

Calling it this way should then work

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{$title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    id: {$contact->id} <br/>
    name: {$contact->name} <br/>
    email: {$contact->email} <br/>
    phone: {$contact->phone} <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Also then you don't need to call this method

```
$smarty->assign('contact',$contact);
```